# MySQL Python: JSON type throws error on assignment

Tags: python, mysql, sql, mysql-connector-python

I am unable to update JSON type cells with `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, as an error is thrown. I am using `mysql-connector-python`. Here is a minimal (not)working example:

First, I define my table as:

```
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE test (
        id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        foo VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        bar JSON NOT NULL
    )
''')
```

Then I try to insert values into the table:

```
val = [
    {
        'foo': 'lorem ipsum',
        'bar': json.dumps({'a': 1}),
    },
    {
        'foo': 'dolor sit amet',
        'bar': json.dumps({'a': 2}),
    },
]
sql = '''
    INSERT INTO test
        (foo, bar)
    VALUES
        (%(foo)s, %(bar)s)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
        bar = %(bar)s
'''
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.executemany(sql, val)
```

Which leads to an error:

```
ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%(bar)s' at line 6
```

If I change the line that says `bar = %(bar)s` to `bar = \'%(bar)s\'`, the code happily executes... at least for the first time, until I run this section again to invoke the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause, which then results in another error:

```
DataError: 3140 (22032): Invalid JSON text: "Invalid value." at position 0 in value for column 'test.bar'.
```

Could you, please, advise me how to fix my syntax?

Comment: You need to re-think the 'ON DUPLICATE' clause. Take that out then use 'INSERT INTO test (foo, bar) VALUES (?,?)'

Comment: @DarkKnight what would then be an alternative to 'ON DUPLICATE'? I want to insert multiple values into a table, however some of these might have the same unique value to another row in the table – in which case I want the rest of the values of the row (apart from the UNIQUE value) to be updated. Isn't 'ON DUPLICATE' the standard way to do this? Or should I differentiate rows which need to be inserted and which to be updated beforehand?

Comment: If that's the case then just remove the UNIQUE constraint on foo

Comment: @DarkKnight I do not want to remove UNIQUE constraint – it is there by design. I need foo to be UNIQUE, therefore removing said constraint, simply so that the example above works, sounds like a really bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`VALUES` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) in the UPDATE clause as well:

> In assignment value expressions in the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause, you can use the VALUES(col_name) function to refer to column values from the INSERT portion of the INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statement. In other words, VALUES(col_name) in the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause refers to the value of col_name that would be inserted, had no duplicate-key conflict occurred. This function is especially useful in multiple-row inserts.

```
sql = '''
    INSERT INTO test
        (foo, bar)
    VALUES
        (%(foo)s, %(bar)s)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
        bar = VALUES(bar)
'''
```